# Non zero exit status error when installing a package in linux

Tags: r, linux

I just installed R on linux. Now I try to install some packages on it. When I try on install the 
the RCurl package using:

```
install.packages("RCurl")
```

I however get the following:

```
* installing *source* package ‘bitops’ ...
** package ‘bitops’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c bit-ops.c -o bit-ops.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c cksum.c -o cksum.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -o bitops.so bit-ops.o cksum.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/marc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/bitops/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (bitops)
* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked 
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/home/marc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RCurl’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpAXtKXQ/downloaded_packages’
 Warning message:
In install.packages("RCurl") :
installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
```

In the beginning everything seems to go fine but then I trows a non-zero exit status error. Any thoughts
what goes wrong here?

Comment: See the `SystemRequirements` section of the description of `RCurl` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html). You need to install the needed system libraries to install RCurl. If you are on Ubuntu, from the command line `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev` will install `libcurl` and then try again to install `RCurl`.